# Replacing labels with names using merge

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to figure out how to do merge. I have a labels.csv which contains the names that I have to use to replace the numbers for the same field in my dat.csv

My dat.csv is as follows:

```
Id,Help in household,Maths,Reading,Science,Social
11011001001,4,20.37,,27.78,
11011001002,3,12.96,,38.18,
11011001003,4,27.78,70,,
11011001004,4,,56.67,,36
11011001005,1,,,14.55,8.33
11011001006,4,,23.33,,30
11011001007,4,40.74,70,,
11011001008,3,,26.67,,22.92
11011001009,2,24.07,,25.45,
11011001010,4,18.52,26.67,,
11011001012,2,37.04,16.67,,
11011001013,4,20.37,,20,
11011001014,2,,,29.63,35.42
11011001015,4,27.78,66.67,,
11011001016,0,18.52,,,
11011001017,4,,,42.59,32
11011001018,2,16.67,,,
11011001019,3,,,21.82,
11011001020,4,,20,,16
11011001021,1,,,18.52,16.67
```

My labels.csv is as follows:

```
Column,Name,Level,Rename
Help in household,Every day,4,Every day
Help in household,Never,1,Never
Help in household,Once a month,2,Once a month
Help in household,Once a week,3,Once a week
```

my programme is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('dat.csv')
labels = pd.read_csv('labels.csv')
df=df.merge(labels,left_on='Help in household',right_on='Name',how='left')

print df
```

However, the names do not appear as I want them to.

```
          STUID Help in household  Maths %  Reading %  Science %  Social %  \
0   11011001001                 4    20.37        NaN      27.78       NaN   
1   11011001002                 3    12.96        NaN      38.18       NaN   
2   11011001003                 4    27.78      70.00        NaN       NaN   
3   11011001004                 4      NaN      56.67        NaN     36.00   
4   11011001005                 1      NaN        NaN      14.55      8.33   
5   11011001006                 4      NaN      23.33        NaN     30.00   
6   11011001007                 4    40.74      70.00        NaN       NaN   
7   11011001008                 3      NaN      26.67        NaN     22.92   
8   11011001009                 2    24.07        NaN      25.45       NaN   
9   11011001010                 4    18.52      26.67        NaN       NaN   
10  11011001012                 2    37.04      16.67        NaN       NaN   
11  11011001013                 4    20.37        NaN      20.00       NaN   
12  11011001014                 2      NaN        NaN      29.63     35.42   
13  11011001015                 4    27.78      66.67        NaN       NaN   
14  11011001016                 0    18.52        NaN        NaN       NaN   
15  11011001017                 4      NaN        NaN      42.59     32.00   
16  11011001018                 2    16.67        NaN        NaN       NaN   
17  11011001019                 3      NaN        NaN      21.82       NaN   
18  11011001020                 4      NaN      20.00        NaN     16.00   
19  11011001021                 1      NaN        NaN      18.52     16.67   

   Column Name  Level Rename  
0     NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  
1     NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  
2     NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  
3     NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  
4     NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  
5     NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  
6     NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  
7     NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  
8     NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  
9     NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  
10    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  
11    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  
12    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  
13    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  
14    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  
15    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  
16    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  
17    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  
18    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  
19    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you want them to appear, can you show your expected results?

Comment: That '\' is  a line continuation character, check below to see if he rest of your merged dataframe is there.  What environment are you coding in?  PyCharm?  Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: @ScottBoston i included the rest of the result

Comment: `right_on='Level'` not 'Name'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, is this what you want?

```
df['Name'] = df['Help in household'].map(labels.set_index('Level')['Name'])
```

Output:

```
Id  Help in household  Maths  Reading  Science  Social  \
0   11011001001                  4  20.37      NaN    27.78     NaN   
1   11011001002                  3  12.96      NaN    38.18     NaN   
2   11011001003                  4  27.78    70.00      NaN     NaN   
3   11011001004                  4    NaN    56.67      NaN   36.00   
4   11011001005                  1    NaN      NaN    14.55    8.33   
5   11011001006                  4    NaN    23.33      NaN   30.00   
6   11011001007                  4  40.74    70.00      NaN     NaN   
7   11011001008                  3    NaN    26.67      NaN   22.92   
8   11011001009                  2  24.07      NaN    25.45     NaN   
9   11011001010                  4  18.52    26.67      NaN     NaN   
10  11011001012                  2  37.04    16.67      NaN     NaN   
11  11011001013                  4  20.37      NaN    20.00     NaN   
12  11011001014                  2    NaN      NaN    29.63   35.42   
13  11011001015                  4  27.78    66.67      NaN     NaN   
14  11011001016                  0  18.52      NaN      NaN     NaN   
15  11011001017                  4    NaN      NaN    42.59   32.00   
16  11011001018                  2  16.67      NaN      NaN     NaN   
17  11011001019                  3    NaN      NaN    21.82     NaN   
18  11011001020                  4    NaN    20.00      NaN   16.00   
19  11011001021                  1    NaN      NaN    18.52   16.67   

            Name  
0      Every day  
1    Once a week  
2      Every day  
3      Every day  
4          Never  
5      Every day  
6      Every day  
7    Once a week  
8   Once a month  
9      Every day  
10  Once a month  
11     Every day  
12  Once a month  
13     Every day  
14           NaN  
15     Every day  
16  Once a month  
17   Once a week  
18     Every day  
19         Never
```

Comment: OK. I understand but that is essentially creating a new column how can I replace or rename?

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much

Comment: In a bigger file I get `pandas.core.indexes.base.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`

Comment: In fact the earlier solution did not work the bigger file created NaNs